# What is the use of isLocal property in jQuery Ajax?

Tags: jquery

I have read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) on the `isLocal` setting that can be passed to the jQuery `ajax()` method.

However, I don't understand what this means:

> Allow the current environment to be recognized as "local," (e.g. the
>   filesystem), even if jQuery does not recognize it as such by default.

I would appreciate an example or use case showing where using it might be useful/appropriate.

Comment: why not check the docs first..!

Comment: @Sudhir I have read the docs. But I am not getting what does this exactly mean : 
Allow the current environment to be recognized as "local," (e.g. the filesystem), even if jQuery does not recognize it as such by default.

Any example or its use case will be helpful.

Comment: @tiger - this is a fine question, but you should include the fact that you've researched it so people don't jump to conclusions. A code sample is even better, e.g. "I tried logging the value of isLocal in scenario ABC but I don't understand why it did XYZ."

Comment: [The jQuery Mobile Docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html) show an example of `isLocal` in "Using the Application Cache". Also note the related discussion in the linked [issue](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1579#issuecomment-1209338).

Answer (score -1):

Default: depends on current location protocol Allow the current environment to be recognized as "local," (e.g. the filesystem), even if jQuery does not recognize it as such by default. The following protocols are currently recognized as local: file, *-extension, and widget. If the isLocal setting needs modification, it is recommended to do so once in the $.ajaxSetup() method.

Syntax:

public bool isLocal { get; set; }

Comment: Is it not what is given in docs !!! I would rather suggest you to read the question before a copy paste :P

Comment: `public`? `bool`? auto-implemented getters/setters? can we now use jQuery to write c#? I'm joking of course, but I'm pretty sure that isn't valid syntax and it certainly isn't showing how to use it.